# FPUTCSV put an array with for loop

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export-to-csv

Hey what I am trying is populate csv with the values from my array. How can I do that ?

```
$sql = "SELECT accountNumber, Name,studentManager,contract,
            nationality,university,major,Course,specialNotes,
            Phone,email,birthday,uniAddress 
        FROM " . $dbname . " 
        WHERE id ='$id'";

$query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$thisArray = mysqli_fetch_all($query2, MYSQLI_NUM);


header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=userData.csv");
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ($thisArray[0] as $row3) {
    fputcsv($fp,$row3);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: In your `foreach` change `$thisArray[0]` to `$thisArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you retrieve the data into `$thisArray`, it creates an array where each row is an array of all the field values.  So when you use `$thisArray[0]` in the following line...

```
foreach ($thisArray[0] as $row3) {
```

This just picks up the first row of the data you've retrieved.  `$row3` will be each individual field and `fputcsv` is expecting it to be an array.

Just change that line to

```
foreach ($thisArray as $row3) {
```

and `$row3` will be each row of data.

(Just so there is an answer for this)